# Is jedi able to autocomplete custom libraries?

Tags: python, autocomplete, dataset, jedi

*I'm a new user to Python, so I don't know exactly what I'm doing. Keep that in mind please :)*

I'm using Anaconda with Sublime Text 3 as my Python IDE.
As I understand, Anaconda uses jedi to find autocompletions for imported packages.

However, when trying the sample script of *dataset*:

```
db = dataset.connect('sqlite:///ebay.db')
table = db['searches']
table.insert [...]
     ^ problem happens there`
```

After the dot, I get no autocompletion of *insert* (or any other functions).
When I try it in the python console it works fine.

I tried to debug it and narrowed down the problem to either *jedi* or *dataset*.
At the Python console:

```
>>> from jedi import Script
>>> print(Script('import dataset;dataset.table.').completions())
```

*Returns:*

```
[<Completion: and_>, <Completion: ClauseElement>, <Completion: Column>, <Completion: DatasetException>, <Completion: ensure_tuple>, <Completion: expression>, <Completion: false>, <Completion: func>, <Completion: Index>, <Completion: index_name>, <Completion: log>, <Completion: logging>, <Completion: normalize_column_name>, <Completion: normalize_table_name>, <Completion: NoSuchTableError>, <Completion: QUERY_STEP>, <Completion: ResultIter>, <Completion: select>, <Completion: SQLATable>, <Completion: Table>, <Completion: threading>, <Completion: Types>, <Completion: warnings>, <Completion: __doc__>, <Completion: __file__>, <Completion: __name__>, <Completion: __package__>]
```

Note there is no `Completion: insert` there.

If I try listing the completions of *dataset.* though, it looks like its working:

```
>>> from jedi import Script
>>> print(Script('import dataset;dataset.').completions())
```

Returns:

```
[<Completion: connect>, <Completion: Database>, <Completion: database>, <Completion: os>, <Completion: row_type>, <Completion: Table>, <Completion: table>, <Completion: types>, <Completion: util>, <Completion: warnings>, <Completion: __all__>, <Completion: __doc__>, <Completion: __file__>, <Completion: __name__>, <Completion: __package__>]
```

As you can see, `Completion: connect` is there, for example.

Am I missing anything? Am I doing something stupidly wrong? Sorry if this is completely trivial.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using these tools? Consider Pycharm, PyDev, Aptana or something that does it out of the box and avoid problems.

Comment: Yeah.. the reason is that I really use SublimeText for everything, it would be better if I could keep it that way. I'll take a look at the tools you mentioned though, thanks!

Comment: @JosepValls "Consider Pycharm, PyDev, Aptana". This is just plain wrong. The tools you listed (apart from Pycharm) are a lot worse when it comes to completions. Nobody is working on completions there. Contrary to thta, Pycharm is a really good tool, but is also not better when it comes to completions. They are probably worse. What they do better is: refactoring, they have a good debugger and linting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this example is that static type inference is way harder than what you do in the terminal. Jedi can work for both, but obviously has a way easier time to succeed with runtime information.

If you look at the code of `dataset`, it becomes clear that it's not trivial to understand what type is being returned. There is a lot of calls that are hard to follow. The big problem here is caching. A dictionary is used to save the tables. Jedi doesn't follow dictionary assignments (yet). This means that while Jedi understands `{'a': 1}['a']`, Jedi doesn't understand `x = {}; x['a'] = 1; x['a']`. Jedi thinks the dict is empty and doesn't look for dict changes. I hope to implement this someday, but it's not easy, because you always have to consider performance.

I have created an issue in the Jedi tracker for this kind of behavior: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/1385. However I'm not sure that will solve this case. What really solves this case is type annotations (or stubs). I'm pretty sure PyCharm has the same issue.

PS: A quick note on your `Script('import dataset;dataset.table.').completions()` where `insert` is missing. This makes sense. `insert` indeed isn't there, it's in `dataset.table.Table.insert`:

```
>>> import jedi
>>> jedi.Script('import dataset;dataset.table.Table.insert').goto_definitions()
[<Definition full_name='dataset.table.Table.insert', description='def insert'>]
```